# How do I change the default app for all programming-related files on MacOS

Tags: macos, code, macos-ventura

Recently switched over from Windows to Mac. First thing that I had to was some stats homework so I installed RStudio to finish that.

After that, I installed VSCode for all my other programming-related tasks but now for some reason all programming files are sent to RStudio by default.

I realize that I can change the default program for each file type but it seems excessively cumbersome to manually switch every single file type when I work with everything from C to TypeScript, especially when MacOS has shown it can auto-fill to a related application.

Is there any way to change the "preferred" code editor for these files?

Answer (score 1):

Not en-masse, you can use Finder & Get Info to change one extension at a time, or it may be slightly quicker to use [SwiftDefaultApps](https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/SwiftDefaultApps) - but only slightly. There's never been anything to truly replace the now defunct [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) which worked up to Mojave but not beyond, for this type of task.